# How to parse json data in nsstring?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am getting response form api like this.

```
{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6ImpvaG4uc21pdGhAZ21haWwuY29tIiwiaWQiOiI1NzFkYzI3NmU0YjA1NjVmNTcwZjM2ZGQiLCJpYXQiOjE0NjMwMjk4NDd9.yi8H75GTS-U8abcS75WcGT5ROfmM0AgCNfRIiZQzeNI","data":{"name":"John Smith","role":"driver"},"message":"success"}
```

But when I try to get value of token it gives me null at the same time when get value of role it give me perfect value.

Please look at my code.

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://qa.networc.in:1336/api/drivers/login"]];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

NSString * params =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@&deviceId=fc2ffdf08ccf0dc912018f7232e4aa0ffcbd856ec3faf4145649f8bb281a779d",_driverNumberTextField.text,_passwordTextField.text];
NSLog(@"params %@", params);

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody =[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
      NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
      if(error == nil)
      {
          // use NSJSON Serlizeitaion and serlize your value
          NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
          NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);

          id object = [NSJSONSerialization
                       JSONObjectWithData:data
                       options:kNilOptions
                       error:&error];
          dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"JSON"];
         NSString *temp;
          temp = (NSString*)[dictionary valueForKey:@"token"];
          NSLog(@"temp %@", temp);

          dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"data"];
          Role = (NSString*)[dictionary valueForKey:@"role"];
          NSLog(@"role %@", Role);
```

Comment: There are many post related to JSON parsing....try to find out that and don't ask similar question.

Comment: You have made a mistake instead of dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"JSON"]; use dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

Comment: where i make mistake sir?

Comment: remove the objectForKey:@"JSON" part as there is no key such as"JSON".

Comment: what the text u get here

Comment: @sanmanborate thanks sir i resolved by remove that line

Comment: we don't need to use objectForKey:@"json". thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do like

```
dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
     NSString *temp =  (NSString*)[dictionary valueForKey:@"token"];
      NSLog(@"temp %@", temp);

NSDictionary *data = [dictionary valueForKey:@"data"];
  NSString *tnamemp = (NSString*)[data valueForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *role = (NSString*)[data valueForKey:@"role"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSJSONSerialization` will return dictionary so you don't need to take `objectForKey:@"JSON"`

replace

```
dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"JSON"];
```

with

```
dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
```

**Suggestion** : Do not parse dictionary again just to retrieve different keys from same dictionary. Use same dictionary.

```
NSString *token = dictionary[@"token"];
NSString *role  = dictionary[@"data"][@"role"];
NSString *name  = dictionary[@"data"][@"name"];
```

Answer (score 1):

//i hope it will work for u

```
  NSMutableDictionary *dic= [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
  NSString *strToke = [dic valueForKey:@"token"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try out the below code: 
The problem is here:

```
dictionary = [[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil]objectForKey:@"JSON"];
```

try out the below code. Hope this helps!

```
NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *responseObj = [NSJSONSerialization
                                 JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                 options:0
                                 error:&error];

if(! error) {
    NSLog(@"responseObj : %@",responseObj);
    NSString *token = [responseObj valueForKey:@"token"];
    NSDictionary *dataDic = [responseObj valueForKey:@"data"];
    NSString *role = [dataDic valueForKey:@"role"];
    NSString *name = [dataDic valueForKey:@"name"];


} else {
    NSLog(@"Error in parsing JSON");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem with fetching keys
Try this,

```
     NSDictionary  *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
     NSString *strToken =  (NSString*)[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"token"];
     NSLog(@"Token %@", strToken);

     NSString *strName = (NSString*)[[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"name"];
     NSString *strRole = (NSString*)[[dataDictionary valueForKey:@"data"] valueForKey:@"role"];
```

Answer (score -1):

Print out single values and check. Access array `$arr["token"]`

Comment: sir i think its in dictionary form not in array?